# having error while starting apache server in xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I am having an error while starting apache serve in xampp

here is the screenshot of the error
[image]

I tried uninstalling it and again installed it but it not working.

I've changes port in httpd.conf file 8080 in place of 80.

I've changes port in httpd-ssl.conf file 443 in place of 4433

please give me some solution to this problem

Comment: share `httpd.exe -t` command output from the Apache httpd  bin folder.

Comment: the output is `Syntax OK`

Comment: start Apache using `httpd.exe -k start` and test.

Comment: this is output `[Thu Jul 23 20:43:04.727887 2020] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 20596:tid 460] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00436: No installed service named "Apache2.4".`

Comment: I've run this command from xampp\apache\bin folder

Comment: could you please check httpd.conf file path and add in command i.e`httpd.exe -k start -f Full path of httpd.conf`

Comment: from where (path) I run this command

Comment: I am getting the same output as the last one